# Предложение с уточнением (имя)

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика

Хочу написать предложение со следующим содержанием:

Отцу Роберта - Роберту Дауни-старшему сегодня исполняется 80, поздравляем!

Верно ли?

Answer (score 3):

**Здесь два варианта, авторский выбор:**

1) Обособленное приложение:

Отцу Роберта, Роберту Дауни-старшему, сегодня исполняется 80, поздравляем!

2) Обособление приложений с помощью тире, увеличенные паузы, бОльшая выделительная способность вставочной конструкции:

Отцу Роберта - Роберту Дауни-старшему - сегодня исполняется 80, поздравляем!

Вариант с одним тире в таких случаях не используется.

Comment: Sibylla, а можно узнать, почему такой выбор? Дело в том, что мне тоже казалось, что приложения с именами собственными обособляются не всегда и здесь как раз такой случай... Но смотрится действительно уместно как уточнение...

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, вариант без обособления  (значение уточнения) также возможен, это схема: нар.сущ+ несоглас. определение перед именем собственным. Выбор авторский, но без обособления текст невыразителен и плохо читается. Сравнить: Брат Марины Павел все дни пропадал на охоте.Брат Марины, Павел, все дни пропадал на охоте. Но: Брат Марины, студент, все дни пропадал на охоте (перед нариц. сущ.)

Comment: @Alenka *приложения с именами собственными обособляются не всегда.* Проостите, что вмешиваюсь, но тут надо говорить о приложениях, ***являющихся***  иенами собственными, а не просто "содержащих" такие имена. Это существенно. Так вот, имена собственные почти никогда не обособляются. Исключения я упомянул в тексте своего ответа.

Comment: Ваши примеры с Павлами и Маринами и студентами совершенно невозможно интерпретировать, не зная, кто они такие, На мой взгляд, обособление возможно, разве что если речь идет о муже   английской королевы, которого все знают как мужа (фактического принца-консорта), но не всякий сходу вспомнит его личное имя Филипп. В таком и подобных случаях приложение лишь уточняет и без того известные вещи и поэтому (и только поэтому) может обособляться. Про незнакомого мне Павла такого сказать не могу.

Comment: Да, я именно имела в виду _"приложения, являющиеся именами собственными"_. Еще когда писала, подумала, что не так поймут... Про уточнение (уж простите мне мою тупость) не поняла... Я-то думала, что приложение в исходном примере обособляется. потому что имеет значение уточнения, а Вы пишете, что как раз уточнение и не обособляется. Совсем запуталась. Я подумала, что есть какое-нибудь правило, что приложения - имена собственные с сущ., обозн. родственников, обособляются. Напр.: _Моя дочь, Анна..._ и т. д.

Comment: @Alenka *Моя дочь, Анна...* - нет, подобных правил конкретно насчет родственников (или кого еще) нет и быть не может. Их нет в принципе, есть здравый смысл и общее понимание того, когда и зачем используется приложение.

Comment: *Про уточнение (уж простите мне мою тупость) не поняла...* - ну если Вам ближе формулировка Лопатина (*которую Серж скопировал, но не понял*) про одного брата, а не про мужа королевы, то я не против. ))))

Answer (score 1):

**Постановка тире в вашем случае возможна.**

Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его): Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.); Отец мой, Клим Торсуев, известный мыловар, был человек тяжёлого характера (Ж. Г.); А братья Ани, Петя и Андрюша, гимназисты, дёргали отца сзади за фрак (Ч.);

**Примечание.** Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении. Ср.:

Один только казак, Максим Голодуха, вырвался дорогою из татарских рук (Г.); Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу; Он сына моего, Борьку, напомнил **(есть только один брат, один сын; если бы было несколько, то при выражении той же мысли собственное имя не следовало бы обособлять);**

**Жене его — Алевтине — не очень хотелось летом в деревню (Шукш.); Обе старшие девочки, Катя и Соня, стали зорко следить за мальчиками.**

См:
[Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

[Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120)

Comment: Точно! Вот именно это я и пыталась вспомнить... И ведь читала же это у пресловутого Розенталя...

Comment: @Alenka Про Розенталя. Мне очень жаль, но ни у Розенталя, ни у Лопатина нет варианта с одним  тире с именем собственным. Будьте осторожны, Серж опять исказил смысл там сказанного. Я уже устал объяснять каждый раз, что ссылаться на Розенталя, не понимая смысла написанного, - медвежья услуга. Читайте (и вдумчиво!) первоисточники, не Сержа.

Comment: behemothus, где я исказил? Вам уже не надоело? Вы сами ничего не понимаете, а пытаетесь всякий раз доказать любыми способами, что ваш ответ самый правильный. Про мужа королевы - какая-то отсебятина. В вашем ответе  одна вода, какие-то непонятные ни на чем не основанные рассуждения.

Comment: Если ваш есть что сказать, приведите правило.

Answer (score -1):

Нет. Приложения, являющиеся именами собственными не требуют дополнительных знаков препинания.  Сравните: *В колхозе "Красный синтаксис" приступили к сбору яровых.*
В принципе, как тут предлагалось, возможно обособление такого приложения (с помощью запятых, парных тире или скобок), но большого смысла ни в данном случае, ни вообще в отношении имен собственных нет. Так что лучше без лишних знаков. Это имело бы некоторый смысл (и то не слишком большой) тогда и только тогда, когда некто (Дауни-страший) известен по своему признаку (как отец Дауни-младшего) больше, чем по своему собственному имени. Не похоже, что здесь это так.